# SessionSwitch is not capturing windows logon events in c# console application

Tags: c#

I have written the following c# console application code for capturing the windows lock/unlock, logoff/logon etc.

```
void SysEventsCheck(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Reason)
    {
        case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
            // Console.WriteLine("sessionlock" + " " + DateTime.Now);                   
            break;
        case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
            Console.WriteLine("sessionUnlock" + " " + DateTime.Now);                   
            break;
        case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogon:
            Console.WriteLine("Logon" + " " + DateTime.Now);
            break;
        case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogoff: 
            Console.WriteLine("Logoff" + " " + DateTime.Now);
            break;
        case SessionSwitchReason.ConsoleConnect: 
            Note("Consoleconnect");
            break;
        case SessionSwitchReason.ConsoleDisconnect: 
            Note("Consoledisconnect");
            break;
    }
}
```

All the events are captured except the windows logon events.
Could anybody help me with this please

Comment: Is it because my console application is not running by that time?, if so is there any other way to capture windows logon through my console app ??